# PHP error object not found

Tags: php, xampp

I have created a small PHP file which displays the name of text files in a directory as `first.txt`, `second.txt`, `third.txt`. On clicking on any of the files I get the error "object not found".

This does not work:

`localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles/first.txt`

But this works:

`file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles/first.txt`

Can you help me to understand what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$directory = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles';

if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')){
    echo 'Looking inside'.$directory.'<br>';

    while ($file = readdir($handle)){
        if ($file != '.'&&$file != '..'){
            echo  '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Following is some updates of log file

- [Thu Jul 18 01:06:57 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/xamppfiles
- [Thu Jul 18 01:15:14 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Applications, referer: localhost/learning/ListingFiles/file.php
- [Thu Jul 18 01:15:43 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Applications, referer: localhost/learning/ListingFiles/file.php
- [Thu Jul 18 01:17:13 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Applications, referer: localhost/learning/ListingFiles/file.php
- [Thu Jul 18 01:39:04 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning/ListingFiles/function.opendir, referer: localhost/learning/ListingFiles/file.php

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path to the get_cwd() current directory?

Comment: shot in the dark here, but i dont think `localhost` is part of the file structure on the machine.. have you tried `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles/first.txt` ?

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 we cant just write "Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles/first.txt"

Comment: @MyStream getcwd() gives the following location '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Learning/ListingFiles
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning/";
```

as your main path with the files in it.

This full path or "../learning" should get you to the right directory to your files.

When creating a link you'll want to use "/learning/" + filename to give the path to the file.

Thanks,
MyStream

Answer (score 5):

Your link doesn't point correctly. When using xampp, the link should be relative to your htdocs folder, not your entire path:

```
/Learning/ListingFiles/first.txt
```

Note, that this would be the same link path you would use if your website were on the net using a domain.

It works when you use file:: because that explicitly states that the path is a file on your computer.

Comment: Ok ,  but then i get the error Warning: opendir(/Learning/ListingFiles/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning/ListingFiles/file.php on line 5

Comment: it may be because you need to include the domain when using opendir: try $directory = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/Learning/ListingFiles";

Comment: also, make sure the path capitalization is correct, on a linux or unix server /Learning is different than /learning.

Comment: btw i'm just following a tutorial on youtube , i did exactly what he did. only difference is i'm on a mac

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33663/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-lochemage)