# Clicked Submit: Object not found

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have created a simple Sign-up php page that uses XAmpp, the problem is every time I press the Submit Button, It just links to a page that says "Object not found" instead of an alert showing Success.

I don't know if there's anything wrong with my code, since there is no error showing, and other registration page I created were almost the same as this one, except this one doesn't add the input in the database.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<?php
session_start();
require 'Connect.php';
$flag=0;

if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])){
    $FirstName = '';

        $flag=1;
    } else
        $FirstName = ($_POST['FirstName']);
    if(empty($_POST['LastName'])){
        $LastName = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $LastName = ($_POST['LastName']);
    if(empty($_POST['Gender'])){
        $Gender = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $Gender = ($_POST['Gender']);
    if(empty($_POST['UserName'])){
        $UserName = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $UserName = ($_POST['UserName']);
    if(empty($_POST['Password'])){
        $Password = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $Password = ($_POST['Password']);
    if(empty($_POST['reEnterPassword'])){
        $reEnterPassword = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $reEnterPassword = ($_POST['reEnterPassword']);
    if(empty($_POST['EmailAdd'])){
        $EmailAdd = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $EmailAdd = ($_POST['EmailAdd']);
    if(empty($_POST['reEnterEmailAdd'])){
        $reEnterEmailAdd = '';
        $flag=1;
    } else
        $reEnterEmailAdd = ($_POST['reEnterEmailAdd']);

        $sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
                 VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$UserName', '$Password', '$reEnterPassword', '$EmailAdd', '$reEnterEmailAdd'); ";

        if($flag != 1){
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result){
              die('Invalid Input: ' . mysql_error().$sql);
            }  
            else{
              echo "<script> alert('Successfully Added'); </script> ";
            }
        }
    ?>

    <head>

            <!-- bootstrap plugin -->
            <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <!-- jquery plugin -->
            <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

            <!-- Site body css -->
            <style type="text/css">
                #SiteBody{
                    width: 1100px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }

            </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <!-- Start header -->
                <img src="../images/logo.png"/>
                <!-- End header -->
            <div id="SiteBody">

                    <!--2nd Header Bar!-->
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <a class="brand" href="#">Sign-Up Form</a>

                            <!--Nav bar items!-->
                            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                                <a href="../homePage.php" class="navbar-link"> Home </a> &nbsp;
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--2nd Header Bar END !-->

                <div class="span9">       
                            <blockquote>
                                <p><strong> Please fill-up the following: </strong></p>
                            </blockquote>          



            <form class="form-horizontal"  action="../php/signUp.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="FirstName"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                First Name: <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="LastName"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                Last Name: <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Gender"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                Type: <select id="Gender" name="Gender" class="input-xlarge">

                <option>Select Gender</option>

                <option>Male</option>

                <option>Female</option>

                </select>
                </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="UserName"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                User Name: <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" placeholder="Enter User Name" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Password"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                Password: <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" placeholder="enter password" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reEnterPassword"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                Re-type Password: <input id="reEnterPassword" name="reEnterPassword" type="password" placeholder="re-enter password" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="EmailAdd"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                E-mail: <input id="EmailAdd" name="EmailAdd" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>


            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reEnterEmailAdd"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                Re-type E-mail: <input id="reEnterEmailAdd" name="reEnterEmailAdd" type="text" placeholder="Re-Enter Email Address" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Button (Double) -->
                <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <but`enter code here`ton class="btn btn-success"> Confirm </button>
                </div>
                </div>  
        </center>

    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710389/php-error-object-not-found?rq=1 check if it helps

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right path for ur form? Also your button doesn't have type="submit"

Comment: `../php/signUp.php` does exist?

Comment: signup.php does exist.
@liquidflo - submit like how it was edited? the "but `enter code here`" ?? D: I'm lost. really. lost.