# PHP: Object not found error on hosted server

Tags: php, xampp

I have hosted my application within an internal server, and it gives the error 
Object Not Found. Error 404

The problem exists only for the hosted application. Not when runs in the local machine.

Anyone know what's the issue here?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than that for us to know what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's like this.

Comment: Probably, you configuration of apache is not correct. You should show it. What is root folder and what you have there?

Comment: give us more information on the error ....for example the error say "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710389/php-error-object-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure ?You have done the correct  configuration settings **.htaccess**